# Close votes don't appear in the activity list of some users?

Tags: support, profile-page, vote-to-close

I recently had a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180479/specjvm2008-vs-java8) closed within less than two hours.
Now, I still think, it's a legitimate question so I edited it, adding grammatically correct questions.

I understand that there must be at least five highly reputed people who like a question to be closed before it is actually closed.

Now, when I look in the **activity list** of those who allegedly closed that question, I can not find their close action, except for two of the five people. So it seems that three of them never closed my question.

Is that a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: i can see all 5

Comment: Where do you look that up - in **activity - review**? The close vote just might not be casted from the review tool but just in the question itself.

Comment: Close votes per user are not displayed to other users.

Comment: In case of Walter, I go to acitvity - all, go back 4-5 pages (right now, Dec 23 spans two pages). Don't see my close.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: I can see five people on my question page, but when checking in their acitivity list, I don't (for three of them).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Then why can I see it for Gnat and ElYusubov?

Comment: @RalfH because activities in the review queue are public... 3 users voted to close directly from the question itself, and it ended up in the Close Vote review queue and 2 more voted from there.

Comment: Incidentally, why is this gathering off-topic votes?

Comment: @Rory people here probably trying to test and see if their close vote is visible in their profile, making a point on the way. (Quite the same like rain of downvotes on any question asking anything like "why was I downvoted")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **activity - review** tab of your profile page you can only see what the tab is called: Reviews casted from the review tool.

If a user opens a question and casts a closed vote then this is not part of the review process and won't be logged in the **activity - review** tab.

So 3 users did not review but casted closed votes directly in the question.

Comment: Yep, worth to mention that your own close votes are visible to you via the profile page --> Votes tab --> closure.

Comment: OKok, I understand. Maybe it was naive on my part to assume that casting a closed votes is an activity, too. I checked all activity, not reviews only.

Comment: @RalfH: As Sha Wiz Dow Ard commented: *Close votes per user are not displayed to other users*